# Power Automate mysteriously changes variable values

Tags: power-automate

Power Automate seems to change variable values mysteriously. I am reading date values from an excel table. If the date value is greater than today's date, I want to blank it, otherwise, I want to write the date to the output file.

I use a variable to hold the date if less than today's date or blank if greater than today's date.

I use a COMPOSE step to view the excel value, a COMPOSE step to view value of variable, SET VARIABLE to set the variable to the date value from excel, and use a COMPOSE step to view the variable value after the set. The value of the variable has changed.

Looking at the run history, here is what I see (sorry, I can't provide a picture. Company machine and I can't install a snagit-like program):

COMPOSE to see excel value:
Input value: 44265
Output value: 44265

COMPOSE to see variable value before SET VARIABLE:
Input value: NA
Output value: NA

SET VARIABLE Step:
Input Value: 44265
Output Value: 44265

COMPOSE to see variable value:
Input value: 42710
Output value: 42710

Any idea why the value mysteriously changes?

Here are screen grabs (I apologize for the piecemeal approach):

[image: Initialize variable]

[image: First Peek at value from excel and variable values]

[image: Set variable with excel value and peek at results after SET VARIABLE step]

[image: Peek at excel value to see it didn't change, peek at variable again, peek at variable at conclusion of condition statement]

Here is the script logic - only tracking down the "NO" condition

[image: Here is the script logic - only tracking down the "NO" condition]

Comment: Can you please show the results of your flow in screenshots bit by bit so we can see it for ourselves?

Comment: I added pictures to my first question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the flow definition, not the results. It’s hard for us to help if we can’t see each step as defined along with any expressions within.

Comment: ok, no problem. more pictures to come.

Comment: Any thoughts concerning why Power Automate mysteriously changes values of variables?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's really hard to follow.  If you can mock up an example flow without all of the connectivity to Excel, etc. and reproduce the problem, you can paste the definition of your test flow into your question and I can import that into my tenant and work through it.  Just make sure your flow is standalone and not connected to anything I'll need access to.

Comment: I tried to recreate the problem by taking the Excel table read out of the equation, as you requested. Was not able to recreate problem. I decided to rewrite the problematic flow from scratch by creating a new flow. So far, I have been able to process the excel table as expected without seeing the issue in the other flow. Obviously, there is something screwy with the original flow. At this point, I'm considering this situation fixed, even though I don't know why the situation occurred. Thanks for your help and desire to help.

Comment: That’s good news.